# What is the record for most consecutive non-intentional pitches called balls?

Tags: baseball, mlb

What is the record for most consecutive balls (not intentional) thrown by a pitcher in the MLB?

Comment: Hi - welcome to the site.  Make sure the question holds the question (and not just the title)- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this record is unknowable, as Major League Baseball has only kept pitch-by-pitch records since 1988.

Given the much lower quality of play in the early 1900s, games such as [the Washington Senators' loss to the Chicago White Sox in 1909](https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=190908281CHA), where the box score records 11 walks by Dolly Gray, [eight of which were in a single inning](https://www.baseball-almanac.com/recbooks/walks_by_pitchers_records.shtml), would be a good candidate - eight straight walks seem to likely have a pretty long strikeless streak in them (especially as players quickly learn to stop swinging at pitches).

However, the modern-day candidate for this record is from a game between [Kansas City and the Chicago White Sox in 2002](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/KCA/KCA200204060.shtml).  In the 8th inning, Miguel Ascencio came in to pitch already down 9-0, in his major league debut, and walked (to lead off the inning!) Kenny Lofton, Ray Durham, Frank Thomas, and Magglio Ordoñez, all on 4 pitches, for 16 consecutive balls.  He was then removed, and Paul Konerko was walked on a 4-1 count by the pitcher to follow him, Cory Bailey; that went 3-0, then a called strike, then another ball.  (One note: MLB doesn't really differentiate intentional balls from accidental ones, with the sole exception of intentional walks; none of these were recorded as an intentional walk.)

So depending on whether you're looking at pitches thrown by a single pitcher or not, 16 or 19 is a pretty good candidate for it.  But it's very possible this was not the record, and instead Dolly Gray or someone else from the early 1900s holds the actual record - but that will never be known.